# How can I get WooCommerce product details in JSON format?

Tags: json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to get all my WooCommerce products with their details (price description, etc.) in JSON. [Here are my consumer and secret keys.](http://www.aaiwa.com/online-shopping/wc-api/v2/products/8637?consumer_key=ck_242ab21965b735bbdc61d4e650cda29ec2712910&consumer_secret=ck_242ab21965b735bbdc61d4e650cda29ec2712910) But I'm getting the following error:

> {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}
>   in response

How can I get all WooCommerce product details?

Answer (score 0):

As noted by the woocommerce docs ( [retrieve a product](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?shell#retrieve-a-product)) you should:

- call the end-point usign https
- pass the key and the secret as basic authentication params (user:password)

You can try with the follow *curl* call:

```
curl -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" 
        --insecure -v 'https://www.aaiwa.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/8637' 
        -u 'ck_KEY:cs_SECRET'
```

- *-H "Accept:application/json"* add header to the request
- *-H "Content-Type:application/json"* add header to the request
- *--insecure* ignore ssl errors
- *-v* dump the headers (request and answer)
- *-u 'ck_KEY:cs_SECRET'* your key and secret
- *'https://www.aaiwa.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products/8637'* the default woocommerce endpoint for the products

About your example link:

- the path it's not the default path (**/online-shopping/wc-api/v2/products**) but depends on your configuration, please adapt the *curl* call to the right one.
- you've used the key instead of the secret ( **consumer_secret=ck_242ab21965b735bbdc61d4e650cda29ec2712910** ), the secret start by **cs_** indeed.

Comment: Where should i write curl from where i should adapt curl call and i have used both keys consumer key and secret key and the path which i mentioned is the default path because i have installed the website in sub-domain

Comment: I assume you're a linux user, so the *curl* command is given inside a terminal. The scope is to do some test. You can use *curl* also online, eg: http://onlinecurl.com/

Comment: Yes I have even tried online but giving error in response headerHTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sat, 26 Aug 2017 10:17:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.25
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.45
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=1auf6u6uck0ob6p852ov6t5ip4; path=/
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8   and   {"errors":[{"code":"woocommerce_api_authentication_error","message":"oauth_consumer_key parameter is missing"}]}

Comment: I have done everything as per the documentation but unable to understand why it is giving the same error

Comment: http://www.aaiwa.com/online-shopping/wp-json/wp/v2/product/8637   through this api I got the json format about the product but unable to get price and other informations